# Get the n first elements from a list where list[i][0] == 'value'

Tags: python

How do I get the `n` first elements from a list of lists where `list[i][0] == 'value'`?

Currently I do these two steps:

```
items = [['value', 0], ['foo', 1], ['value', 2], ['value', 3], ['bar', 4]]
n = 2

tmp_list = []
for item in items:
    if item[0] == 'value':
        tmp_list.append(item)

i = 0
while i < n:
    print(tmp_list[i])
    i += 1
```

The expected results in this example are `['value', 0]` and `['value', 2]`.

It works but it doesn't look very neat. I have a nagging feeling it can be done better, I just can't find the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-do-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Comment: Why do you collect them in a new list, and why do you collect more than n, if you only want to print the first n? Do you need that larger list for something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first improvement would be to use a list comprehension for the first step, and slicing for the second step:

```
tmp_list = [item for item in items if item[0] == 'value']

for val in tmp_list[:n]:
    print(val)
```

Then you could change it to a generator with lazy evaluation. Whether that is an improvement is debatable and depends on what else you intend to do with these values.

```
from itertools import islice

values = islice((item for item in items if item[0] == 'value'), n)

for val in values:
    print(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are three approaches to this problem.

#### Lazy

Using a lambda that returns a list comprehension followed by a slice.

```py
take = lambda arr, key, n: [e for e in arr if e[0] == key][:n]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [['value', 0], ['foo', 1], ['value', 2], ['value', 3], ['bar', 4]]
    print(take(arr, 'value', 2))
```

#### Better

Creating a function that stops iteration once the desired amount has been reached.

```py
def take(arr, key, amount):
    res = []
    for item in arr:
        if item[0] == key and amount > 0:
            res.append(item)
            amount -= 1
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [['value', 0], ['foo', 1], ['value', 2], ['value', 3], ['bar', 4]]
    print(take(arr, 'value', 2))
```

#### Best

Decoupling the `amount` by utilizing a generator and `islice` to grab the desired amount.

```py
from itertools import islice

def take(arr, key):
    for item in arr:
        if item[0] == key:
            yield item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [['value', 0], ['foo', 1], ['value', 2], ['value', 3], ['bar', 4]]
    print(list(islice(take(arr, 'value'), 2)))
```

The shorthand for the generator is the following list comprehension:

```py
def take(arr, key):
    return (item for item in arr if item[0] == key)
```

Comment: What's lazy about the "lazy" one? And the "better" one doesn't stop iteration.

Comment: And that at the end is not a list comprehension but a generator expression.

Comment: Ah I guess you don't mean [lazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation?wprov=sfla1) but the *programmer* being lazy...